# I need to use powershell to add a txt file as mail body(not attachement),is there anyway to do that?

Tags: email, powershell

$mail.Subject = "testforloop";

$mail.Priority  = "normal"

$mail.Body = #I need contents form a txt file here (e.g. D:\results)#

Any good ideas to deal with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` to read the text file into a string:

```
$mail.Body = (Get-Content "myFileName")
```

`Get-Content` has parameters that allow specifying the encoding etc..